# Deserialize JSON request Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jwt

Please help me with this:

> Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
>    at [Source: org.springframework.mock.web.DelegatingServletInputStream@2b92e1c6; line: 1, column: 14] (through reference chain: br.com.foca.api.config.jwt.RESTUser["user_name"])

My Class:

```
@Data
public class RESTUser {

@JsonProperty(value = "user_name")
private String userName;
private String password;
}
```

My Request:

```
 MultiValueMap<String, String> param = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    param.add("user_name", "X");
    param.add("password", "Y");

    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(param);

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    header.add("Origin", "LocalTest");

    ResultActions result = mvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")
                    .headers(header)
                    .content(json)
                    .accept("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
```

The problem occurs on this code below:

```
    RESTUser creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), RESTUser.class);
```

I'm using jackson to manipulate the objects.

Comment: In your request code, try creating an actual `RESTUser` object, and call `String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(restUser);`

Comment: I found the problem, i change the line:
    MultiValueMap<String, String> param = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
to 
    Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();

Thanks to your attention